# exposed email properties via the API

Tags: outlook-addin

I would like to get email statistics, and create an addin for that. I was wondering if the outlook API for developers exposes properties like:was an email replied/was an email marked for followup.

Comment: Is that for a JS based addin or a COM based addin?

Comment: Hi Vadim, I would prefer the JS addin,but if the COM addin is richer in possibilities, I might try it as well.